# Overlay image on top of plotly plot (SVG)

Tags: html, css, svg, plotly

I have a chart in a div, generated by plotly (which is a SVG element). I want to overlay an image on top of that, but I cannot figure out how to do it. I have tried setting the background-image CSS property on the div to the image, but it does not show up. Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple Overlay...

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/2L6r3mL5/)**

**Code:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ploty">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x300" />  <!-- This would instead be your chart -->
  </div>
  <img class="overlay" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/1/" />
</div>


.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

This positions `img.overlay` at the top left corner of `div.wrapper`.  You can place it anywhere you want by changing the values of the `top` and `left` properties like this:

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!